# How can i read sysfs attributes

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, sysfs

How can i read sysfs attributes from user app. It is similar content from cat command. Such as I have a tag is brightness. How can i get the value of brightness tag? Because i need to read the USB infor from my app and i see they were exported to sysfs like below topology:

```
ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1
1-1:1.0              busnum               port
authorized           configuration        power
avoid_reset_quirk    descriptors          product
bConfigurationValue  dev                  quirks
bDeviceClass         devnum               removable
bDeviceProtocol      devpath              remove
bDeviceSubClass      driver               serial
bMaxPacketSize0      ep_00                speed
bMaxPower            idProduct            subsystem
bNumConfigurations   idVendor             uevent
bNumInterfaces       ltm_capable          urbnum
bcdDevice            manufacturer         version
bmAttributes         maxchild
```

Comment: So you are apping, not programming?

Comment: I am writing a module for USB device so i need to do that.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-usb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file using e.g. `fopen("//sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/version", "rt")` and read its contents like with any other file. Not sure about brightness, you don't mention which file its in and there's no file with that name.

Comment: I need to read many file inside /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1 folder, if i use this way, should i have to to open all of files as i need? Is there any way to open only /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1 folder but i can read all contents inside it?

Comment: @Gun: Any file under `/sys` is semantically a regular file. For read it you should have it opened, no other way. Normally, it is not a problem to have ~30 files opened.

Comment: After your comment to your question, it looks like an XY problem and you ran into the wrong direction. If you really want to write a device driver, this is definitively the wrong approach.

Comment: @unwind: For my last question, is there any way to get these information from user app (maybe ioctl), except reading file by file?

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, my program is user app, not device driver ~